# ListView Activity & Dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I've a listView Activity where user could open a dialog to display more information about a line of the list.

On the Dialog user could modify a line. So my purpose is to refresh listView when User modify it by the Dialog.

The problem is that I couldn't use myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanges() so How I could do that ?

Comment: why could you not use notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Because there is a "null pointer exception" like i'm not in the ListActivity.

Comment: please add some code excerpts to illustrate how you're trying to accomplish this

Comment: I achieve it with bundle. I dismiss dialog, call the same activity and just change parameters without load all the list.

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using a database to populate the list, or perhaps some kind of array. Why don't you simply create a function that fills the list. Every other method that is called that might change the data in the list would simply modify the content in the database for instance (update, add) and then call the list filler method. This puts all the code for filling the list in one place that can be easily called whenever you need it.

Comment: in fact, I use Server call to populate the list.